# GATLING- Feeder crashes for empty row, when ramping up the users

Tags: scala, csv, gatling

I want to reuse the same csv feeder for multiple virtual users (eg: 2 users) and process all 713 records by both the users.
Looks like it is sharing the feeder.
I would like each user to process all 713 records in the csv file separately, by 2 or more users. Can you please advise how to run the same scenario with more users that should re use the same csv file - and should process all 713 records each time?

```
  val submit: ScenarioBuilder =
    scenario("Submit")
      .exec(Submission_round1())

      setUp(
        Simulation.inject(
          nothingFor(1),
          atOnceUsers(1),
        ).andThen(submit.inject(nothingFor(1),
          //atOnceUsers(1)
            rampUsers(2).during(20)
        ))
      )
```

when running the method only once, it runs with no error, all 713 records were processed, however when i increased the user load to 2, it errors out with the error
Simulation BiddingSimulation completed in 137 seconds
11:19:34.724 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder csv(ATL-AUS-Round-1.csv) is now empty, stopping engine
at io.gatling.core.action.FeedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FeedActor.scala:83)

```
val feederRound_1 = csv("data/data-1.csv").shuffle

     def Submission_round1(): ChainBuilder =
        pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
          .exec(Submission(713, feederRound_1))
    
     private def Submission(noOfRuns: Int, feeder: BatchableFeederBuilder[String]): ChainBuilder = {
        pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
          .repeat(noOfRuns) {
            feed(feeder)
              .exec(postToUri(s"${config.baseUrl}/base-orders/order", s"Submit orders for : #{$orderId}")
                .queryParam("employeeId", "#{empNo}")
                .body(StringBody(session => {
                  println(session)
                  println(session.attributes("empNo"))
                   
                }))
              )
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like each user to process all 713 records in the csv file separately, by 2 or more users.

That's not how feeders work. You'll have to implement your own thing.

Comment: i found from the documentation that virtual users shares the same feeder, so can i use circular in order to use the same feeder file by multiple virtual users, to achieve what i want?